# Не получается установить Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Создаю установочную флешку в Win8 с помощью **unetbootin**, далее в **Boot Priority** биоса ставлю **usb**.
Далее запускаю **Install Ubuntu Server** и далее тормозит, выдает сообщение что необнаружен CD-ROM.
Пробовал методы описанные на других ресурсах, не получилось. Может кто сталкивался и нашел решение, подскажите.

Comment: Ну, делайте через компактный диск.

Comment: @LEQADA В сервере нету cd-rom, внешнего тоже нету, единственный вариант usb.

Comment: Под виндой использую программу **Universal USB Installer** для записи iso-образов c дистрибутивом линукс. Предлагаю попробовать. Эта программа никогда не подводила. С остальными программами записи были проблемы...

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы в BIOS сервера USB-устройства не эмулировались как CD-ROM.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov попробовал, не получается.

Comment: @kff как это сделать ?

Comment: @Goldy Здесь только один рецепт - зайти в BIOS и искать. Даже у десктопов BIOS разный, а у серверов так вообще зоопарк. Ищите что-нибудь типа *USB Device emulation*, *Threat USB devices as* и т.п.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что раз вы где-то запускаете "Install Ubuntu Server", то загрузка с флешки стартует, а на отсутствие cdrom вам жалуется уже установщик Ubuntu Server? Вы можете или в установщике нажать Alt+F2, выйти в консоль, и там смонтировать `.iso` файл с флешки в `/cdrom/`, либо вместо unetbootin сделать флешку прямой записью образа, через UltraISO или [Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо народ! Установил через Rufus в DD режиме и все установилось.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить флешку в разъем USB 2.0 или отключите поддержку USB 3.0 в BIOS. Называться этот пункт меню может по разному: USB Debug, USB Legacy Support, что-нибудь со словами XHCI Mode (такой режим нужно отключить), или что-нибудь похожее.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй записать через  [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/Archive/Win32DiskImager-0.9.5-install.exe/download).